# Коммиты в два проекта

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

Создал новый проект, привязал его к репозиторию, всё в принципе как надо.
Но решил не через консоль коммитить потом, а через VCS.

И собственно сразу проблема, почему то он мне предлагает сделать коммит в двух репозиториях
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно удалить второй репозиторий отсюда, чтоб в будущем мог без проблем коммититься.

Comment: `$ git remote show` сколько хранилищ показывает?